# python regex split first character

Tags: python, regex, split

e.g. I have Name : **John Frank Smith**

What I want is to seperate by first space

so array will be ***[0]=John [1]=Frank Smith***

what I tried, I replace space by ~ and tried to split by regex.

```
import re
s="John~Frank~Smith"
l=re.compile(r'/~(.+)?/').split(s)
```

output is:

```
 ['John~Frank~Smith']
```

How can I achieve as described above?

first I don't know how to put space in regex.

Comment: To put a space in a regex you _put a space in the regex_.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with the `maxsplit` parameter:

```
>>> s = "John Frank Smith"
>>> s.split(None, 1)
['John', 'Frank Smith']
```

**Note:** This will split on multiple occurrences of whitespace, so a string like

```
John    Frank Smith
```

would give the same result. If you only want a single space as a separator, use `s.split(' ', 1)`.

Comment: Care: `s.split(None)` will split on _all_ whitespace, not just space. This may or may not be what is wanted.

Comment: @katrielalex: Yes, I thought it would be sensible in this case, but I'll mention it separately

Comment: A suggestion, why not: `s.split(maxsplit=1)`, don't need `None`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a regex:

```
>>> re.split(r'~', "John~Frank~Smith",1)
['John', 'Frank~Smith']
```

The `~` are from your example.

Answer (score 0):

no need for regex, use split() :

```
s="John~Frank~Smith"
s.split('~',1)
```

`['John', 'Frank~Smith']`